# Nginx multiple Link headers in same request

Tags: nginx, web-server, http-headers

In Apache if I make a request that contains multiple `Link` headers, it will merge them into one comma separated list.

In nginx, if I make the same request all but the last are discarded

For example, with the following request:

```
PUT https://example.org HTTP/1.1
Link: </some/path>; rel="parent"
Link: </another/path>; rel="child"
```

Using Apache, the PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_LINK']` variable will contain the following:

```
</some/path>; rel="parent", </another/path>; rel="child"
```

However in nginx, the variable will be:

```
</another/path>; rel="child"
```

Is there a feature toggle in nginx config I can turn on to mimic Apache's behaviour?

**UPDATE:**

I should add that I am using PHP-FPM as a fastcgi_pass. I added the following to the nginx config which passes the first `Link` header instead of the last:

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_LINK $http_link;
```

I wonder if there's any way to access `$http_link` as an array and split it myself in the config file.

Comment: Did you try a `var_dump()` with nginx to see if your variables might be somewhere else inside the array?

Comment: @notStan Yes, I inspected the entire `$_SERVER` array

Comment: Just an idea (didn’t check) you could try to parse raw headers with lua https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/master/README.markdown#ngxreqraw_header

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known bug in nginx: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1316 and https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1762

The original ticket is over two years old now which is disappointing as it doesn't seem to be a priority for the devs.

The only solution I can think of for now is to parse the `Link` headers at the client end and combine them into one before the request is made.